# Java. Работа с файлами

Tags: java, intellij-idea, excel, ms-word

Я твёрдо решил быть  программистом. На данный момент изучаю Java SE. Да вот уже и подумываю написать свою первую программу. Пришла идея вот какая: " Написать программу-словарь, параллельно изучаю English, на Windows был ABBYY Lingvo, а на Linux нету".

Вопрос в следующем:
Работа с файлами, база данных — пока еще рановато, но вот записывать в файл — как раз. Думаю создать два `.txt`  файла , в один писать слово на англ., а во втором его перевод + сделать поиск по файлам, но нужно сделать поиск в файле по номеру строки, реально ли это в текстовом документе или нужно в excel? Жду ваших предложений.

Comment: Может один файл будет лучше? `csv`, например)